# enable button in C# by removing 'disabled' property using firebug

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question about disable button (C#) that I need your help.

in Asp.net (C#), disable the button code:

```
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.click += new EventHandler(btn_click);
    btn.Enabled = false;
    btn.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
```

The generated HTML:
        **<input type="button" disabled="disabled">**

The button is disabled until I use **firebug** and **remove the 'disabled' property** and **change the type property to submit** (**<input type="submit">**) then user can click on btn and it can perform **btn_click** method(postback).

How could we prevent this issue? I try to use CommandName (disable, enable) to mark disable button and inside btn_click method, I check if **CommandName== "disable"** then stop the function but it is very messy.

Thanks for your help.
Van

Comment: You can't stop anyone changing the content in the browser. You will need to handle this issue server-side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Client can remove the Disabled attribute but cannot change the control ViewState. On server side you can do that:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (btn.Enabled)
     {
           // do something         
     }
}

<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Enabled="false" OnClick="btn_Click" Text="Test" />
```

Comment: I tested with asp.net 4 and when I remove the disabled attribute at the client side, I find Enabled is true on the button click, even though I have set it to false on Load.

Comment: Did you do like my example above?

Comment: My bad, some problem with the dlls going to the server. Works perfectly.

Comment: Normally one would expect the asp.net mac validation to take care of this, like it does for disabled inputs(not sending their data to the server). Too bad this requires a manual check.

Comment: The decision of sending or not must be made on client side and I believe anything on Client side can be hacked. Validation should be applied for both side.

Answer (score 3):

You can't control your users' behavior.What you need to do is handle these things in server-side..

you can judge the button's status in btn_click.. and then do some work

Comment: Can you suggest how might the status be checked?

Comment: @nunespascal just look at what namkha87  said.

Comment: thanks you. You're right.  the namkha87 's solution below worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

@bystander is right.  You need to check on the server whether that condition is correct.  You can't rely on the client being 100% fool proof, and that's the exact reason why.

Can you hide the control instead, and reenable it on some future postback?  Hiding doesn't actually render the control to the client at all.